# In Gmail, can I show only unread emails for a label as a Section

Tags: gmail, priority-inbox

I'm using the Priority Inbox, and want to add a Section with only unread messages from a label.

The section dropbox allows me to select a label, but shows all messages in the label (including read ones).

Earlier I was using the "Multiple Inboxes" from Gmail Labs which allows for creation of an Inbox section using a custom search. Is this possible using Priority Inbox sections?

Comment: The problem is: where would the unread emails get filtered to? Sounds impossible to me.

Answer (score 6):

A little bit late, but since I found this as the first result when searching for this very issue, I should add that it's possible.

> 1. Set up the priority inboxes and your labels, if they aren't already.
> 2. Apply a filter to archive "work" messages coming in so they skip the main inbox.
> 3. Go to Settings > Inbox > Options next to the inbox section you want to customize.
> 4. Click "More Options..."
> 5. Right-click or CTRL+Shift+C on the label (e.g., "work") and select "Inspect element." (Firefox users just go to Tools > Web Developer > Inspect Element and click on the label).
> 6. Look for the attribute cfg="^all,Work" and change the value to cfg="^u,^all,Work"
> 7. Finally, select the work label on the page as normal.

As seen on:
[Customize Gmail's Priority Inbox View with a Super Simple Hack](http://lifehacker.com/customize-gmails-priority-inbox-view-with-chromes-dev-1065561971)

Answer (score 2):

As of 2019 the hack provided by @Kaue Lima doesn't appear to be working. Instead it seems better to use the "multiple inbox" feature that Gmail has added.

1. Setup your labels and filters
2. Under Settings > Inbox choose "Default"
3. Under Settings > Advanced choose "Multiple Inboxes" and Save your Changes
4. You'll have a new tab under settings called "Multiple Inboxes"
5. Go to your general gmail inbox and create a search with OR / AND, multiple labels, status etc. Copy the working search into the "Multiple Inboxes" tab under settings.

Comment: Unfortunately as of Feb. 2021 it no longer seems possible to use both the "default" GMail inbox style (with categories) and the multiple inbox style (with custom searches).

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021 it's easier to do that.

Click "Settings"

[image]

Then, in the drop down menu, select "Unread first"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with the following:

- create your first label "work" with the corresponding filter.
- create a second filter "label:work is: unread", and for this filter apply a new label "work unread"
- Then in the Settings > inbox > section settings, you can choose the label "work unread".

Also note that this section must be place above the section "unread" because an email that can appear in 2 sections will display in the first one (the one more on top).